# Basic DOMXpath, can be wrong? (re: check input namespace always)

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am using a internal domDocument into a class, `$this->doc->dom`, and I think that is ok because `$this->doc->dom->saveXML()` works, and show my XML, something like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>04</title>
      <link href="css/04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
   ...
```

And when I use

```
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($this->doc->dom);
 $elements = $xpath->query('//link');
```

no error reported... But, no elements (!),

```
   print $elements->length;
```

show 0 (zero). **That is the problem**, and for me is a DomDocument BUG: the `<link ../>` element is there!

---

Edit to add more clues...

When I do similar thing with `getElementsByTagName()` it works (!), so, is not a problem with the `$this->doc->dom`.

```
 $test = $this->doc->dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
 print $test->length; // OK, not zero, returns 1!
```

Comment: Not sure how DOMXPath() works but you should try registering the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace with `$xpath->registerNamespace('xhtml', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");` and then run `$xpath->query('//xhtml:link');`

Comment: YES (!), now the bloody query is working!

Comment: When in trouble in cases like these try a tool like http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. In your example it throws an error that would have lead you to the solution: `The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a "DomDocument bug".

## Simple solutions

Consolidating the posted comments.

### Register the namespace

*(@PaulT answer)*  
The root (`html` tag) have a namespace declared, `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.
With `registerNamespace()` you can register it, with an arbitrary nickname (xx), then do a correct query

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('xx', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"); 
$xpath->query('//xx:link');
```

### Remove namespace attribute from root

I an filtering my input, so it changed to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>04</title>
    <link href="css/04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
...
</html>
```

now is working as I expected, without need of "damn namespaces".

## Debugging XPath

*(@RolandoIsidoro answer)*  
When in trouble in cases like these try a tool like [freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html). 
In your example it throws an error that would have lead you to the solution:

> The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' 
>    and it cannot be redefined to 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'