# There are a minimal DTD for ID resolution?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, dtd

I would like to [solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19102916/287948) by an ugly hack: declaring a "false DTD" to my "any XML"... Explaining with an example:

INPUT (any XML fragment)

```xml
<root id="root">
  <p id="p1"><i>Title</i></p>
  <p id="p2"><b id="b1">AAA<sup>1</sup>, BBB<sup>2</sup></b></p>
</root>
```

PHP code,

```php
   $DTD = '
   <!DOCTYPE noname [
   <!ATTLIST ANY
      id     ID             #IMPLIED
   >
   ]>';

   $dom = new DomDocument();
   $dom->loadXML( "$DTD\n$input" );
   $e = $dom->getElementById('p1');

   var_dump($e);
```

This code is not a solution: $e is NULL, and I not see why... So, the question: **is possible to express a "minimal DTD" that solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the ID mechanism to work, the simplest option is to use [**`xml:id`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/):

```
<root xml:id="root">
  <p xml:id="p1"><i>Title</i></p>
  <p xml:id="p2"><b xml:id="b1">AAA<sup>1</sup>, BBB<sup>2</sup></b></p>
</root>
```

According to https://fosswiki.liip.ch/display/BLOG/GetElementById+Pitfalls, `xml:id` should work with `getElementById` in PHP.

---

Problems with your attempt:

1. The element name following `<!DOCTYPE` must match the name of the root element of the XML document. In your case, `noname` != `root`, which does not work. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd.
2. Attributes must be declared for each element. You cannot declare attributes for `ANY`. And even if the content model of an element is `ANY`, you still have to declare all the elements that may occur.

So there is no way to create a DTD just for ID resolution. The following validates, and it cannot really be smaller than this:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root (p+)>
<!ATTLIST root
         id  ID   #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT p ANY>
<!ATTLIST p
         id  ID   #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT b ANY>
<!ATTLIST b
         id  ID   #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT sup (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT i (#PCDATA)>
]>
<root id="root">
  <p id="p1"><i>Title</i></p>
  <p id="p2"><b id="b1">AAA<sup>1</sup>, BBB<sup>2</sup></b></p>
</root>
```

---

It is possible to provide a smaller DTD as long as the XML parser does not attempt to validate. This document is accepted by xmllint (and by PHP) in non-validating mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE anyname [ 
<!ATTLIST p id ID #IMPLIED> 
]>
<root id="root">
  <p id="p1"><i>Title</i></p>
  <p id="p2"><b id="b1">AAA<sup>1</sup>, BBB<sup id="b1">2</sup></b></p>
</root>
```

And ID uniqueness violations on `p` elements are reported.

If xmllint is run with the `--postvalid` option (or PHP is run with `LIBXML_DTDVALID` enabled), this is emitted:

```
test.xml:4: element root: validity error : root and DTD name do not match 'root' and 'anyname'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, useful and self-explained answer. Yes, it seems that my "dream minimal" not exists, but I am using a smaller and it works (!), `<!DOCTYPE anyname [  <!ATTLIST p id  ID   #IMPLIED> ]>` -- Yes it is working without use of elements or name "root"... Perhapts this is the "minimal possible" (accepted by a [libXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) parser, that PHP use).

Comment: I'm a little confused right now... When running xmllint (libxml2) with the `--postvalid` option, I get `element root: validity error : root and DTD name do not match 'root' and 'anyname'`.

Comment: hum... Perhaps PHP use  "more permissible/non-restrictive" options, it runs with the 3-line PHP code above.

Comment: I suspect that this has to do with the difference between a validating and a non-validating parser. When xmllint is run without `--postvalid`, it runs in non-validating mode and no error occurs (it just registers the attribute declaration). And that is likely also what happens when the PHP code is executed.

Comment: ... Yes (!), see [PHP  options for libXML2](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php). If I use loadXML with `LIBXML_DTDVALID` option,  errors are issued "*No declaration for attribute id of element root in Entity*", "*root and DTD name do not match 'root' and 'anyname'*".

Comment: Well, final answer: there are a "minimal DTD" with DTDVALID (you showed) and other without DTDVALID (I showed). No "minimal DTD" is perfect, all need one ATTLIST for each identifyed-element-name.

Comment: Of course, your issue/clue about `xml:id` is "near to perfect" (!), I am trying to use with other things like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)... And learning how to distinguish pure `id` from `xml:id` with xpath (needs [registerNamespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18725000/287948)) , getElementById (how libXML2 checks differences if you have a DTD?).